# Why some or all identity references could not be translated

Tags: c#, iis-7, expression

In the visual studio 2010, there is no error and everything works fine, but when I publish to IIS once an error

line:

```
Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Preset pres = Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Presets.VC1IISSmoothStreamingSD480pVBR;
```

error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
some or all identity references could not be translated
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Examine the stack trace for more information about this error and where it originated in the code.

  Exception Details: System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException: some or all identity references could not be translated.
```

**update:**
I'm getting the same error from line:

```
var job = new Job();
```

namespace:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder;
using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Profiles;
using VideoSmooth.Domain.Abstract;
using VideoSmooth.Domain.Entities;
using VideoSmooth.Web.Models;
```

Comment: What is the application pool mode? (Integrated, classic?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set ApplicationPoolIdentity in pool iis and it worked without error